# How to affect only one delegate listener in C#?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, events, delegates

So I have a ManaScript and a ManaBar on every Player. The problem is, that the Manabar listens to every OnManaPercentChanged, so that even though every gameObject has it's own ManaScript and I call ModifyMana on one specific instance, the ManaBar gets updated for every player. How should I proceed to only change one ManaBar?

### ManaScript:

```
[SerializeField] const int maxMana = 100;
int currentMana;  

public event Action<float> OnManaPercentChange = delegate { };

private void Awake()
{
    currentMana = maxMana;
}


public void ModifyMana(int amount)
{
    currentMana += amount;
    float currentManaPct = (float)currentMana / (float)maxMana;
    OnManaPercentChange(currentManaPct);
}
```

### ManaBar:

```
[SerializeField] private Image foregroundImage;

private void Awake()
{
    GetComponentInParent<PlayerMana>().OnManaPercentChange += HandleManachanged;
}

private void HandleManachanged(float percent)
{
    foregroundImage.fillAmount = percent;
}
```

Comment: Debug your code. I would assume especially the Awake method. Check if the call to GetComponentInParent delivers the component you are expecting. If not look at the code you don't show and ask yourself why.

Comment: I think it depends on how your heirachy is set, but, from this with a normal heirachy, there is only 1 manabar and 1 manascript in a tree (eg mob -> body/stats/manabar) so it would only update the relevant bar

Comment: As the other said, the problem as to do with how your hierarchy is setup, and which component the `GetComponentInParent` is returning. Delegate Listener aren't static, so everything would work if you were subscribing to different instances. Meaning the issue you are encountering is that you are subscribing to the same instance.

Comment: You need to modify your delegate to accept source object as parameter. And you should modify the source object instead of instance.

Comment: The HandleManachanged() method is a callback and should be declared like ever other callback event.  It need to have as a parameter the instance of the PlayerMana.